# Serving S3 with Cloudfront content to a client

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to serve an S3 Cloudfront to a client.  They own and control their domain `clientdomain.com`
The client specified `admin.clientdomain.com` to be the name of S3.

Now I have created an S3 bucket with specific name `admin.clientdomain.com` and configure Cloudfront with it and it produced
the corresponding domain name `abc123xxx.cloudfront.net`

I provided the client with these info (`admin.clientdomain.com ---> abc123xxx.cloudfront.net`)
so they can create a CNAME in their DNS Manager the entries.

When I browse for `abc123xxx.cloudfront.net` it shows the page and website contents, but when I try to browse for `admin.clientdomain.com` it errors to:

> 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. Bad request. We can't
> connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There
> might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later,
> or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to
> customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and
> help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
> rt8tyVw7z08KccR0blotyc9IlgBzybuaEJ

**Additional Info:**

- We do not have WAF
- Set the Distribution to accept "HTTP and HTTPS"
- Default root Object ponted to "index.html"
- On Behaviours, Cache Based on Selected Request Headers is set to "None"

**Questions:**

1. I still get the 403 Error message
2. As per googling, it was mentioned to populate the Cloudfront Distribution's "Alternate Domain Names": "admin.clientdomain.com" with ssl
3. DO i need to get the client's SSL certificate?  How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple potential problems here, let's try to rule them out one by one.

Verify that the following URLs are available and serve content:

- `https://<your-distribution-id>.cloudfront.net`
- `http://<your-distribution-id>.cloudfront.net`

We don't know if the CNAME record is set correctly. To verify that you can use a tool like `dig` to check the CNAME record, e.g. `dig CNAME admin.clientdomain.com` - Make sure it points to the CloudFront domain.

Make sure `admin.clientdomain.com` is in the "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" in your CloudFront distribution. When that's the case, at least http should be working.

Try to access: `http://admin.clientdomain.com`

If that works, we've made progress. Now on to HTTPS/SSL/TLS. In order for CloudFront to be able to serve HTTPS content for admin.clientdomain.com, it needs a Certificate. Fortunately you can use the Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) to [request a free one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html). Create a certificate for `admin.clientdomain.com` in ACM **in the region us-east-1 (North Virginia)** and then configure CloudFront to use that certificate. Note that your client will have to add additional DNS records to verify they own `admin.clientdomain.com` - alternatively you can import an existing certificate into ACM.

Afterwards you should be able to access `https://admin.clientdomain.com`.